# mysql insert into tbl (select from 2 table)

Tags: mysql, sql

As the title says I am trying to insert into 1 table selecting values from 2 tables. The query gives me an error

```
INSERT INTO def 
SELECT * from table1, table2
Where time = table1.time
```

Comment: you need to specify which cols to select and make sure the selected cols match with table definition of table def

Answer (score 0):

`def` table columns definitions must be equal to joined `table1` and `table2` columns definitions. Otherwise you must define what column in `def` table to map with output of SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

First, learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax. *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Your query is returning an error because, presumably, both tables have a column named `time`.  So, you need table aliases or `using` clause.

Second, always list the columns explicitly, both for the `insert` and the `select`.  Do not depend on default ordering.  So, a properly written query would look more like this:

```
INSERT INTO def(col1, col2, . . . )
    SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2, . . .
    FROM table1 t1 JOIN
         table2 t2
         ON t2.time = t1.time;
```